# How can I convert a text value to a numerical value?

Tags: sql

I have a column called FREQUENCY with 4 possible values:

```
Every 3 Months
Every 6 Months
Every Month
Every 4 Weeks
```

I would like to convert these values to numerical values. 1/3, 1/6, 1, and 4 respectively so that I can perform equations on them.

How can I convert these values to the said numerical values? Is there a way to tell the system, for example, that "Every Month" should be displayed as a numerical 1?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Use `CASE` statement

```
Select
Case when FREQUENCY = 'Every 3 Months' then 1/3.0 -- added .0 to avoid integer division
     When FREQUENCY = 'Every 6 Months' then 1/6.0
     When FREQUENCY = 'Every Month' then 1
     Else 4
End
```

**Update :** If you want to `1/3` instead of `0.333` then make it as string

```
Select
Case when FREQUENCY = 'Every 3 Months' then '1/3'
     When FREQUENCY = 'Every 6 Months' then '1/6'
     When FREQUENCY = 'Every Month' then '1'
     Else '4'
End
```

**Note :** You need to make all the result expression as string to avoid implicit conversion

Comment: Good answer, but the op might want `'1/3'`, `'1/6'`, `'1'` to be displayed, rather than numbers.

Comment: Thanks Gordan, I assumed as numbers because of this line *I can perform equations on them* May be am wrong

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Added it in answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using "case" statement you can get values what you want.For example:

```
select FREQUENCY,  
case FREQUENCY  
when 'Every 3 Months' then 1/3  
when 'Every 6 Months' then 1/6  
when 'Every Month' then 1  
when 'Every 4 Weeks' then 4  
else -1  
end  
from your_table;
```

1.Take a look at the result of this statement. You could get your numeric values using `case` statement as described above.
2.You can add a `float` field to your_table:

```
alter table your_table add (newfield float)
```

3.Initiate your `newfield` by desired values according to FREQUENCY field values.

```
update your_table set newfield =   
case FREQUENCY
when 'Every 3 Months' then 1/3  
when 'Every 6 Months' then 1/6  
when 'Every Month' then 1  
when 'Every 4 Weeks' then 4  
else -1  
end
```

4.Use your `newfield` to calculate whatever you want.